# Does CSS have any plans to support variables?

Tags: css, css-variables

I know I can use frameworks ( http://lesscss.org ) to accomplish this but I was wondering if pure CSS will support this any time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does CSS have any plans to support variables?

More than plans, it has a [W3C candidate recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/), implementations such as Chrome [here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6401356696911872) and Firefox [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-variables-land-firefox-31/), and and Edge implementation roadmap [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/cssvariables). Here is a [full support matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), showing they are currently available in FF and Chrome.

A google for "css variables" brings up the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), which describes the current situation in good detail.

> I know I can use frameworks (http://lesscss.org) to accomplish this

True CSS variables obey the cascade. In that sense, they are quite a bit more powerful than variables as implemented in pre-processors such as LESS (which is a pre-processor, **not** a framework, by the way).

Comment: I don't see why most front-end jobs emphasize these frameworks.  CSS variables will make that code kind of less than ideal.

Answer (score 5):

There is [a Draft Spec for CSS variables](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/) that you might want to read about.

Here's an example of the syntax:

```
:root {
  --main-color: #06c;
  --accent-color: #006;
}
/* The rest of the CSS file */
#foo h1 {
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

Not sure on browser compatibility as of now. I think Chrome and Firefox might support it, but I doubt IE does.

Comment: Browser supports can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: If you're not sure about browser compatibility, you could check caniuse.

Answer (score 0):

Today, we are 40% global users supporting **CSS Variables** as you can check here:
http://caniuse.com/#search=variables (aka **Custom Properties**)

Answer (score -1):

Probably not and probably because of cross browser compatibility. Imagine setting up colours in your style sheet as variables and someone using an older or less supported browser might not have the capability to read variables and as such the site wouldn't get any colour! I would just use pre-processors like SASS to solve this problem.

Comment: never let the past hold you back!

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this. I had no idea but should be interesting!